# Почему глаголы изменяются по родам только в прошедшем времени?

Tags: глаголы, род, времена, историческая-грамматика

Понятно, что языки упрощаются. Особенно "языки межнационального общения". Чем не пользуются - то отмирает.

Но вот вопрос: нужно ли было на практике изменять глаголы по родам?

- Если да, это должно было сохраниться во всех временах.
- Если нет, это должно было исчезнуть во всех временах.

Как же так получилось, что изменение глаголов по родам сохранилось только в прошедшем времени?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78698/discussion-on-question-by-arioch--------).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Заметьте: языки далеко не всегда упрощаются! Но разговор не об этом.

Сейчас я постараюсь рассказать о грамматической системе древнерусского языка, который является прямым предком русского языка.

В древнерусском языке было несколько форм прошедшего времени глагола: **аорист** (практически не встречается в бытовой и деловой письменности; употреблялся для обозначения действий или состояний, целиком отнесенных к прошлому и не расчлененных на составные моменты, – например, *купихъ* 'я купил'), **имперфект** (как и аорист, относится, скорее, к церковнославянскому языку; обозначал длительное действие в прошлом, не ограниченное во времени и не связанное с настоящим, – например, *писахъ* 'я писывал' (вспомним выражение *еже писах, писах*)), **перфект** (обозначал состояние, которое является результатом некоторого действия в прошлом: например, *пришьла еси* '(вот) ты (и) пришла') и **плюсквамперфект** (форма, связанная с последовательностью действий в прошлом, – грубо говоря; например, *азъ **быле** лони **наделиле*** 'я **в прошлом году выделил** надел в имущество').

Обратим внимание на то, как образовывались формы перфекта: форма настоящего времени глагола *быти* + **причастие** на *-л* смыслового глагола. Если глагол *быти* не зависел от категории рода, то для образования подходящей формы причастия род субъекта был необходим. Со временем вспомогательный глагол *быти* отпал.

Современные формы прошедшего времени глагола типа *(я) слышала* являются потомками перфекта без отпавшей глагольной связки (*есмь, еси* и т. п.) и изменяются по родам именно потому, что восходят к **причастию**, которое как раз обязательно согласуется в роде с субъектом.

---

Почему другие глагольные формы не согласуются в роде?

Опять же по историческим причинам. Они восходят к формам будущего и настоящего времен древнерусского языка, которые не зависели от рода.

*Использовалась «Историческая грамматика русского языка» Е. А. Галинской (М.: Ленанд, 2016).*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78934/discussion-on-answer-by-aer--------).

Answer (score 4):

"*Изменять глагол по родам*" означает "**согласовывать глагол с родом существительного**", с которым (из числа имеющихся в предложении) его требуется связать, поскольку **род** - принадлежность существительного, а *не* характеристика выражаемого глаголом *действия*. В общем случае для **связи** с существительным (местоимением) глагол может модифицироваться не только по роду, но и по другим признакам. Для выполнения или облегчения такой функции связи нет принципиальной необходимости глаголы всех времен изменять именно под род существительного. У глаголов *настоящего* и *будущего* времени связь с нужным существительным облегчается выбором **личной формы** (1, 2 или 3 лица). У глаголов *прошедшего* времени таких форм нет, поэтому понадобился *другой признак*: согласование по **роду**.

Насколько же необходимо изменять глаголы введением в них дополнительных связующих признаков?

В каждом языке это происходит по-своему.

В *китайском* глаголы не имеют даже времени, что не мешает выразить время модальными частицами, вспомогательными глаголами или однозначным внешним контекстом; связь же глаголов с существительным обеспечивается более жёстким, чем в русском, порядком слов.

Другой крайний случай и полезная аналогия: какие ещё признаки можно добавлять к глаголу для связи его с существительным. В языке *суахили* в состав глагола включается до трёх подряд префиксов (приставок), которые "маркируют" производителя действия, его адресата (с учётом принадлежности соотв. существительного к одному из 9 грамматических родов и ед./мн. числа), время глагола; в ряде случаев используются префиксы, обозначающие смысл "уже" или "ещё не"; при этом может изменяться окончание глагола и добавляться суффикс наличия "бенефицианта" действия (для кого оно производится) между корнем и окончанием глагола. В русском глагол намного проще, но для улучшения обратной связи с ним у существительных есть падежные формы (в суахили же есть только аналог "местного" падежа).

Многообразие или единообразие связей глаголов с существительными вряд ли свидетельствует о степени развитости того или иного языка. Все три упомянутых являются языками межнационального общения. Сохранившиеся связующие признаки вполне могут быть информационно избыточными: во многих случаях избыточность способствуют повышению разборчивости речи, что имеет значение в условиях вариаций произношения на крупных территориях, где используется язык. Из крупных "упрощений" можно отметить разве что административную реформу письменности в КНР (упрощение написания части сложных иероглифов).

Comment: `административную реформу письменности` я имел в виду естественные процессы, типа отмирания падежей в английском языке. Административные реформы в таком случае просто фиксируют "на бумаге" уже реально сложившийся порядок вещей, а не изменяют его. /// Влияние "гастарбайтеров", для которых язык не родной и используется только в необходимом минимуме, никуда не денется. При прочих равных (конечно, не всегда все прочие факторы равны) это будет вести к ускоренному упрощению, сравнительно с языками где "прагматичных малообразованных чужаков" нет и нижняя планка выше.

Comment: Просто сравниваем количество времён в современном и древнем русском языке, или количество падежей (в современном русском вроде бы выделяют до 16 исторических падежей, но все кроме стандартных полноценных 6 - только остатки былого, свернувшиеся до очень специфических и относительно редко используемых выражений)

Comment: `У глаголов настоящего и будущего времени связь с нужным существительным облегчается выбором личной формы` - очень хорошее замечание. Действительно, это наверное связано. Но на вопрос "почему" сложилось так, почему в одном времени глаголы выбирают один способ связи, а в другом - другой, тоже не отвечает. Будем ждать сравнительных примеров от AER  :-D

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ 1**

**Вопрос некорректен.** Глаголы не делятся по родам, а изменяются по родам.

Это означает, что они имеют **форму прошедшего времени**, для образования которой используется суффикс Л и окончания, соответствующие разным родам в ед.числе (во мн. числе  **род не выражен** ни у существительных, ни у глаголов).

Для образования **формы настоящего и будущего времени** используются личные окончания, выражающие грамматическое **значение лица и числа**.

Грамматические значения глагола используются **при образовании грамматической связи между  подлежащим и сказуемым**, а для это достаточно согласования **двух показателей:** рода и числа или лица и числа.

**Никакой симметрии, указанной автором в качестве обязательного условия развитого языка, здесь не требуется.**

Такая система сложилась **исторически**, **и она успешно выполняет свою функцию.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

https://studopedia.ru/14_16812_istoriya-form-proshedshego-vremeni.html

Общая история форм прошедшего времени – это процесс постепенного отмирания синтетических временных форм (**аориста и имперфекта**) **за счет расширения функций перфекта.**

Сложная семантика перфекта выражалась сложной по составу формой: вспомогательный глагол быти в настоящем времени сочетался **с кратким действительным причастием прошедшего времени с суффиксом –л-.**

Современная форма прошедшего времени, **исторически связанная с древнерусским перфектом,** способна выражать весь спектр значений, которые в древнерусском языке выражались **целой системой форм прошедшего времени.** Современной видо-временной формой прошедшего времени на –л- в определенных типах контекстов обозначаются:

1) Длительное или недлительное действие как **конкретный факт прошлого** **(аористическое значение**). Например:  В гимназии он не доучился, попал потом в одну военную школу, потом очутился на Кавказе, выслужился, дрался на дуэли, был разжалован, опять выслужился…(Ф. Достоевский).

2) Прошедшее действие, результат **которого актуален для более позднего временного плана** – настоящего или прошедшего (**перфектное значение**). Например: Лесов все меньше и меньше, реки сохнут, дичь перевелась, климат испорчен (А. Чехов);

3) Прошедшее действие, представленное **в процессе его протекания** (может быть подчеркнуто элементами структуры предложения или контекста), прошедшее постоянное или прошедшее повторяющееся и обычное действие, что нередко совмещается с квалифицирующим, качественным оттенком – **имперфектное значение**. Названные оттенки имперфектного значения обычны для глагольных основ **несовершенного вида**. Например: Чем более он напрягал мысль, тем только яснее ему становилось, что это несомненно так (Л. Толстой);

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78935/discussion-on-answer-by-jasmin--------).

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ 2**

**Перед нами вопрос, получивший семь голосов одобрения, такое, согласитесь, редко встречается.** В едином порыве мы выражаем свой восторг... о вот пред чем? Давайте прочитаем повнимательнее его подредактированный вариант (где глаголы хотя бы уже не склоняются, как в варианте начальном).

"**Понятно, что языки упрощаются. Особенно "языки межнационального общения". Чем не пользуются ― то отмирает.
Но вот вопрос: нужно ли было на практике изменять глаголы по родам?
Если да, это должно было сохраниться во всех временах.
Если нет, это должно было исчезнуть во всех временах".**

Ключевое слово ― ***должно***. Вероятно, именно оно произвело на окружающих такое **магическое действие**, тогда с ним и разберемся.

Итак, автор уверенно рассматривает **симметрию грамматических значений как показатель развитого языка.** Возможно, он исходит из того, что симметрия является основополагающим принципом устройства мира, и она действительно характерна, к примеру, для живой природы или архитектурных форм. Симметрия и асимметрия, два начала, единство и борьба противоположностей.

**Но, может быть, и в языковых системах действует принцип симметричности?** Это сложная философия, но если рассматривать в качестве симметрию **наличие или отсутствие  грамматического значения рода для глаголов в настоящем и прошедшем времени, то она явно отсутствует** (и в современной, и в исторической версии языка), то есть символом гармонии, красоты и совершенства в данном случае никак не является. Но, по-видимому, автор, утверждающий своё "должно",  уверен в обратном.

Но язык ― экономная система, и **развитость его заключена скорее в минимальном количестве грамматических форм**, которые обеспечивают необходимые функции. Так что **магическим оказалось количество, равное двум**: лицо и числи или род и число.

Но об этом уже было сказано, а я хотела бы обратить внимание на следующее: как автор представляет себе  с**ловоизменительную систему глаголов в настоящем времени с тремя грамматическими значениями: род,число, лицо?** Он что, добавит новые окончания или суффиксы какие в качестве маркеров рода? И откуда всё это возьмется, ведь это же не реформа, а исторический процесс, эволюционное развитие форм.

**Поэтому я не голосую за этот вопрос**, но с интересом понаблюдаю, сколько еще голосов он наберет (это тоже любопытный показатель). Я по-прежнему считаю  его **абстрактным, умозрительным** и говорящим прежде всего о том, что автор мало разбирается в предмете, о котором берется рассуждать

Comment: Я тоже с интересом _наблюдаю_ (и только). А Ваши знания и опыт безусловно интересны и полезны.

Comment: Спасибо, ваше мнение важно для меня. Рекламный такой текст получился, но это действительно так.

Comment: Да уж какое — именно моё-то? Для того чтобы не выглядело "рекламой", с удовольствием могу добавить — **_пользительные!_** (ТАК говорил мой дед; я люблю это слово.)

Comment: @Информация для всех. Дорогие коллеги и друзья! Пожалуйста, оставляйте комментарии, когда вы минусуете ответ. С чем вы не согласны? Неужели вы считает, что система грамматических значений у глаголов должна быть симметричной? Что конкретно вам кажется неверным?  Я же не против темы вопроса (она нужная, познавательная), я против рассуждений автора на эту тему. Но ведь другие участники форума тоже отметили, что вопрос "почему" неправомерен, не имеет ответа.

Comment: Да, я тоже считаю, что "отрицательная" оценка **требует комментария**, чтобы разобраться — в чём же однозначно состоит _неверность_ ответа. Мною были оценены оба Ваши ответа — как полезные.

Comment: Я могу предположить, что не всем нравится общий тон моего ответа, но это же полемика. Я ничего не имею против автора, возможно,  надо положительно оценить его любознательность, нестандартный подход, может быть, это будущий серьезный исследователь русского языка.  Но тогда не надо его защищать, неужели он нуждается в вашей защите? Критика пойдет ему на пользу, а если не пойдет, то и исследователя не получится.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова и Jasmin, пожалуйста, помните, что такие обсуждения значительно эффективней на Мете: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Обсуждать не будем, но только люди, которые минусуют информацию по непонятным причинам, не участвуя в обсуждении, наносят ущерб сайту.

Comment: Я согласен, что, когда минусы пояснены, значительно легче найти недостатки в ответе или вопросе. Тем не менее минусы также могут использоваться, например, если участник не согласен с ответом (при этом точка зрения изложена корректно, и придраться не к чему). Неужели в этом случае необходимо писать: «Я с вами не согласен. Точка!»? Тема, которую вы обсуждаете, совсем не простая — но минусы, как и плюсы, совершенно неизбежно встречаются в истории репутации каждого участника, который активен на сайте, поэтому не стоит огорчаться. Наоборот, это должно быть стимулом к развитию и совершенствованию!

Comment: Спасибо, совершенствоваться и развиваться обязательно нужно,  этим я  и займусь, а то  больше  для других стараюсь. И огорчаюсь только за форум, потому что минусы разные бывают. Вот  зайдет кто-нибудь на сайт и увидит, что все дружно проголосовали за симметрию грамматических форм,  а никакой симметрии нет и быть не может. Но я ситуацию, разумеется, учту, так как надо понимать настроение аудитории. Прежде всего попробую сократить объем ответов  и потраченное время до минимума и никому ничего  больше не объяснять. Неблагодарное это дело и часто бесполезное.

Answer (score 1):

Подобные вопросы с "почему" обычно не имеют ответа. "Потому что гладиолус". Так сложилось в языке. Причинно-следственная связь не прослеживается. Исторический обзор того, как этот процесс происходил, вам дали, не буду повторяться.

Я добавлю только, что "изменяются по родам" как термин не намного лучше исходного. Правильно говорить ***"Категория грамматического рода представлена у глаголов только прошедшего времени".***

Я попробую ответить на неявный вопрос о предопределенности самого факта изменений в пользу прагматического подхода ("все ненужное отмирает"). Нету такого. Вернее сказать, тенденция такая есть, но чаще "ненужному" находится новое применение. Здесь как раз тот самый случай. Отмершему функционалу "Л-формы" причастия "нашли" как раз подходящее применение. Род объекта можно не указывать. Как ни странно, это куда более информационно нагруженное свойство, чем согласование по грамматическому лицу-числу, как у глаголов настоящего-будущего времени. Сравните: глагол "быть" в настоящем времени сначала потерял все формы, кроме *есть* (а их было аж девять - для трех лиц  и трех грамматических чисел - http://www.philol.msu.ru/~tezaurus/docs/1/articles/3/3/5). А потом и вовсе принял нулевую форму всюду, кроме единичных случаев использования формы третьего лица "есть". А в прошедшем - вот все четыре формы живы.

Теперь анекдот в тему.
*Как немцу объяснить сложность грамматического рода русского глагола? Да очень просто. Вот увидели вы сидящую на улице кошку (ну или зайца). Как сразу узнать, кот это или кошка? Да очень просто. Спугнуть её. Если **убежал** - значит кот. А уж если **убежала** - точно кошка.*

Вот это и есть пример современного использования "неиспользуемого" атрибута категории грамматического рода глагола прошедшего времени.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78936/discussion-on-answer-by---------).